# Getting shapefile with change information of two different year's shapefiles?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile

I have two shapefiles of different years.

Now, I want to get the change shapefile to show in the form of polygons, and in the table also so that I also can the data of change category

Comment: are you able to provide an example with images?

Answer (score 1):

If you have two shapefiles having same geometry like in Point or Line features, then you should

(1)Add both files in your project
(2)Convert your feature class into polygon feature (By using tool of Features to polygon )

**NOTE: Path of tool

1-Toolbox   2-Data Management Tool 3-Features 4-Features to polygon.**

(3)Export the data in new shapefile.

Now you have a shapefile with polygons and attributes are also present in this shapefile.

If you have shapefiles have already in polygon feature class then, there is no need to convert it. because its already in polygon.

Comment: thanks, but i have two polygon shapefiles. i want my output shapefile will show that the change in polygon. like if i have a polygon of any category (grassland) in first shapefile. and same polygon with more area in second shapefile. so in output shapefile, for same polygon two polygon will show , 1 is for no change in category and other is for change category.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, add both shapefiles in your project (.mxd).
2. Clip the second shapefile with the reference of first shape file.
3. Change the information of attributes of second shape file as per your requirement.
4. Now export the both shapefile as one.

**NOTE: Just like given image.**

[image: EXAMPLE]